An integrated amplifier circuit with current mirror transistors will not amplify the input voltage (Vin)
I can't figure out why my Multisim amplifier circuit isn't amplifying the DC input voltage. I double-checked the settings for each transistor, as well as my calculated gate voltage for transistor Q1, which was around 2V.
My student number is xxxxx67 so my β = 167.






I double-checked the settings for each transistor, as well as my calculated gate voltage for transistor Q1, which was around 2V. First of all, I don't know why you have to calculate a gate voltage for Q1. What's the significance of that? Secondly, the circuit you made in the first picture, clearly shows a 5V supply at that gate of Q1, which looks like your "Vin", using your second picture as reference, so I don't know what you mean by 2V. Lastly, and I could be wrong since it's been a long time since I've done this sort of thing, it looks like you're inverting your output.

Do you know what a small-signal gain quantifies? What are small signals? Is deviating by 3 Volts from your initial bias point considered small? If not, can you trace that voltage on a DC transfer characteristic and see what the output should theoretically be? Does it match your simulation?

I made a mistake and uploaded the wrong image, it's all good now, and I connected the AC signal with the DC bias voltage in series to get the circuit working.

I made a mistake and uploaded the wrong image, the correct image should have a DC bias voltage of 2V connected to the gate of Q1.
And I connected the small AC input signal with the DC bias voltage in series at Q1's gate terminal to get the amplifier circuit working properly now.
